# cocoa pods breaks svn

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, svn, cocoapods

I am working on a Xcode project with SVN and things work fine (committing, update etc).

One day I have decide to install the AFNetworking through cocoaPods since it was a folder with its files inside my project.

first I removed AFNetworking files, and once the pod successfully installed then I launched the myProject.workspace, the structure of the project was right and every thing is fine except the svn seems not function in the right way, I mean if I select a file and look at its 'Source Control' on the left side menu, I can't see the info related to SVN, also if I made a change the 'M' letter doesn't appear.

[image: Any selected file inside my project looks like this one]

has anyone faced this one before? I don't know what exactly is going on,,, please help

Comment: Which file do you select?

Comment: Any .h .m file inside the project @rounak